# How to create a presence-absence matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have an Excel table (.csv), like this (with duplicate species):

```
Species     Site 
Panthera    A 
Panthera    B 
Panthera    C 
Neofelis    B 
Neofelis    D
```

and I would like to use R to create a presence-absence matrix, like this:

```
Site    Panthera    Neofelis
A          1           0
B          1           1
C          1           0
D          0           1
```

How I could do it, please?
Thanks!

Comment: `table(df[2:1])`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I cannot find information about the function of the arguments [2:1]. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: I just reordered the columns in order to match your desired output. You could as well just do `table(df)` but then the result will be transposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, Site~Species, length)
```