# Creating a 'presence-absence' matrix from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dcast

I have data in the form of a pandas dataframe similar to that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790891/how-to-create-a-presence-absence-matrix).
That is:

```
Species     Site 
Panthera    A 
Panthera    B 
Panthera    C 
Neofelis    B 
Neofelis    D
```

And I want to create a presence-absence matrix like so:

```
Site    Panthera    Neofelis
A          1           0
B          1           1
C          1           0
D          0           1
```

How would I go about performing this operation in Python as opposed to R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df['Site'], df['Species'])
Species  Neofelis  Panthera
Site
A               0         1
B               1         1
C               0         1
D               1         0
```